# Hibernate one-to-one mapping with a reference column (XML mapping)

Tags: java, database, hibernate, one-to-one

I have a user table and a `user_detail` table with one to one mapping `user_detail` table have a field `user_id` to be used for this relation which stores id field value of corresponding user.

How to write the hibernate `hbm` file for this relation?

UPDATE

what my problem is that user's primary key is `id` , user_detail's foreign key is `user_id`

all the examples i got in internet users user_id as users primary key and the same as foreign key in other table

Comment: Have you tried something? This is pretty straightforward and you could have found an example in one of the many Hibernate tutorials out there.

Comment: i looked at many examples but all gives same case, in my case we always give PK as id, how to define that user_detail table's field user_id is relates to the user table id field

Comment: @RaulGogo : I have edited the question to make it clear

Comment: Posted an answer which actually solves the above requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For User mapping....**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
        <!-- Generated 25 April 2011 7:52:33 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
        <hibernate-mapping>
            <class name="com.rais.User" table="USER" catalog="mydb">
                <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Integer">
                    <column name="USER_ID" />
                    <generator class="identity" />
                </id>
                <property name="userName" type="string">
                    <column name="USER_NAME" length="10" not-null="true" unique="true" />
                </property>
                <property name="userCode" type="string">
                    <column name="USER_CODE" length="20" not-null="true" unique="true" />
                </property>
                <one-to-one name="userDetail" class="com.rais.UserDetail"
                    cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
            </class>
        </hibernate-mapping>
```

**For UserDetail mapping.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Generated 25 April 2011 7:52:33 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.rais.UserDetail" table="USER_DETAIL"
            catalog="mydb">
            <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="USER_ID" />
                <generator class="foreign">
                    <param name="property">user</param>
                </generator>
            </id>
            <one-to-one name="user" class="com.rais.User"
                constrained="true"></one-to-one>
            <property name="compName" type="string">
                <column name="COMP_NAME" length="100" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="compDesc" type="string">
                <column name="COMP_DESC" not-null="true" />
            </property>
            <property name="remark" type="string">
                <column name="REMARK" not-null="true" />
            </property>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: its many-to-one relation na, i need one-to-one, also users primary key name is id and the foreign key in user_detail is user_id

Comment: did you understand what i need?

Comment: @prashu132 modified answer to meet your requirement. Please see above code.

Comment: Thanks dude `<generator class="foreign">
                    <param name="property">user</param>
                </generator>` was the thing i needed. Works fine now.

Comment: can you give a sample code for creation and updation for user with user_detail

Comment: a very good example here. http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-using-annotations-1.html

Comment: i have tried `UserDetail userdetail= new UserDetail();

  userdetail.setUser(user);
  ... other values....
  
  user.setUserDetail(userdetail);
  update(user);`

... Its fine when user details is new, when i try again (user detail already created) its gives error instead of updating values.  

Error is , 

**org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:**

Comment: @prashu132 Why has the answer been accepted? I though your requirement was Having user_detail_id as primary key in UserDetail and a separate column user_id as foreign key. This answer uses same column for both primary and foreign key in UserDetail.

Answer (score 6):

In the User.hbm you need to declare the relation with UserDetails like this:

```
<one-to-one name="user_detail" foreign-key="user_id" class="UserDetail full name "/>
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Now how do we get "delete" to work if user_detail is null when calling update()? Tried `cascade="all"` and `cascade="all,delete-orphan"` but neither work

Answer (score 3):

For one-to-one associations where primary key of UserDetail is not the foreign key, we have to represent it as many-to-one association on the owning side.

From Hibernate docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html

> Alternatively, a foreign key with a unique constraint, from Employee to Person, may be expressed as:

`<many-to-one name="person" class="Person" column="PERSON_ID" unique="true"/>`

> And this association may be made bidirectional by adding the following to the Person mapping:

`<one-to-one name"employee" class="Employee" property-ref="person"/>`

So, there is no way to map this association using one-to-one, you have to change the mapping to many-to-one on the owning side (Table holding the foreign key).

Answer (score 0):

```
<one-to-one name="user_detail" class="give the full specified className with package declaration" cascade="save-update"></one-to-one>
```

Here is an good example

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-relationship-example/

please find it.

Comment: i looked at many examples but all gives same case, in my case we always give PK as `id`, how to define that user_detail table's field user_id is relates to the user table `id` field

Comment: got any idea about my scenario?

Comment: also the link you gave was the first thing i checked while i started got stuck in this